# Use a Boolean variable that will act as a switch in the code. If the user still has guesses remaining out of the 3

Tags: python

My program is a guessing game that has three questions the user tey to guess the answers of the 3 questions and they have only three chances if they did make three mistakes the program restart again but if they answer the 3 questions before their 3 chances finished they get their score at the end.

**The problem**

When the user enters a wrong answer from their first try it automatically goes to the second question.

```py
 number_of_guesses = 0
 print("Guess the Animal\n")
 while number_of_guesses < 3:
    number_of_guesses += 1
    guess1 = (input("Which bear lives at the North Pole?"))
    if number_of_guesses == 3:
      break
    if guess1 != ("polar bear"):
        print("please try again")
    else:
        print("correct answer")
    guess2 = (input("Which is the fastest land animal?"))
    if number_of_guesses == 3:
      break
    if guess2 != ("cheetah"):
        print("please try again")
    else:
        print("correct answer")
```

I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
Guess the Animal

Which bear lives at the North Pole? grizzly
Sorry Wrong Answer, try again teddy

Sorry Wrong Answer, try again black

The Correct answer is polar bear

Lob Kei We Ran asa Tie ia ote hn Bie Molo tee)

Correct Answer

Which is the largest animal? elephant
Sorry Wrong Answer, try again blue whale
Correct Answer

Your Score is 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function returns `True` when the question is answered correctly and `False` otherwise:

```py
def question(q, a):
  for i in range(3):
    x = input(f'{q}\n' if i == 0 else 'Wrong answer, try again:\n')
    if x == a:
      print('Correct answer')
      return True
  print(f'The correct answer is "{a}"')
  return -1
```

To support multiple questions and print the total score in the end you can try:

```py
questions = {
    'Which bear lives at the North Pole?': 'polar bear',
    'Which is the fastest land animal?': 'cheetah',
    'Which is the largest animal?': 'blue whale',
}

print(f'Your score is {sum(question(q, a) for q, a in questions.items())}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start again at the top of the while loop when they have given an incorrect answer.

So, you see wherever you have `print("please try again")`.
After this, put down `continue` in a new line.

This will cause the program to start again at the top of the while loop.